# what is the fastest way to solve equations having more than two variables of 1 degree?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have four equations for four variables
$$a+b+c+d=0$$ $$5a+3b+2c+6d=10$$ $$12a+21b+c+4d=30$$ $$2a+3b+4c+5d=40$$

Now what is the fastest way to find a, b, c and d?

I know of elimination and substitution out of which elimination takes lesser time. Is there any faster way than that?

I took these equations (which are written above) arbitrarily.

Comment: have you heard about Kramer's rule?

Comment: For *fast* algorithms see the MSE question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30330/fast-algorithm-for-solving-system-of-linear-equations).

Comment: @Mihail Cramer's rule is a bit big if i am suppose to find all variables.

Comment: @Mihail: Cramer's rule is not really practical for large number of unknowns, because computing the determinants can get unwieldy. It is nice to have for _theoretical_ reasons-- it shows that the components of the solution (if the solution unique) are rational functions of the coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In general*, unless you happen to find a particularly nice relation between the coefficients that you can exploit for a shortcut, Gaussian elimination on the augmented matrix is the way to go for manual calculations. There's a reason that is what is taught in beginning linear algebra courses!

Comment: Your advice + patrickJMT video = My solution. Just one last simple question. What kind of equations are these which I wrote. Are these linear equations?

Comment: @manshu: Yes, they are linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is "fastest way". What I would do is to inverse the matrix associated i.e. inverse $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\5&3&2&6\\12&21&1&4\\2&3&4&5\end{pmatrix}.$$
But it's quite a long work too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the coefficients have special patterns (e.g. $x+y=4$ and $x-y=2$, we immediately have $2x=6$ and $2y=2$ and so on), we hardly find any short cut.  I'd suggest eliminating equations with small coefficients first.